# error Rails 5 <class> must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, factory-bot

A creation of this delivery model ought to work after being attached to a user...

```
class Delivery < ApplicationRecord
  enum kind_of: { package: 0, facturation: 1 }
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :orders, foreign_key: "package_delivery_id"
  has_many :invoices, foreign_key: "invoices_delivery_id"
  has_one :address
  has_many :runs, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

...yet, in my spec

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe OrderPolicy do
  context 'toegang' do
    subject { OrderPolicy.new(user, order) }
    let(:user) { create :user }
    let(:delivery) { create :delivery, sender: user }
    let(:order) { create :order, customer: user, status: 'open', package_delivery: delivery }
    let!(:selection) { create( :selection, :product_name         => 'Honingpot',
                                           :product_quantity     => 4,
                                           :product_price        => '5,00',
                                           :product_mail_weight  => '460',
                                           :product_sales_tax    => 6,
                                           :order                => order) }

...
```

and also this one:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe DeliveryPolicy do
  context 'toegang' do
    subject { DeliveryPolicy.new(user, delivery) }
    let(:user) { create :user }
    let(:delivery) { FactoryGirl.create :delivery }

...
```

...I get the error:

**Delivery must exist**

While I have the user there. (`optional: true` also didn't work, btw.)

Strangely enough, all I need in the console to make a `Delivery.create` to get working is adding in a `sender: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

"A creation of this delivery model ought to work after being attached to a user..." - Thats the problem? Then you can do:

```
class Delivery < ApplicationRecord
  enum kind_of: { package: 0, facturation: 1 }
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User', required: false
```

Since Rails5, `belongs_to` by default adds `required: true`